# Script tag doesn't work either relatively or directly on react

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs

I am starting to learn react. I installed react using npm, deleted everything that I didn't need, but when I put the index.js on src and index.html on public it didn't work and when I tried to load it or when I try to use VS built in relative path it takes the index.html as index.js and it says that there is not any file in that path I really don't understand why it doesn't work. please help
ps: even though there isn't anything in the index.js it still gets me this error here is the link command:

```
    <script src="index.js"></script>
```

Comment: use `create-react-app`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `npm create-react-app myappname` to generate a full fledged react template. Deleting stuff at the early stage is a bad idea. You can use the command `npm eject` inside the react-app folder to eject out all the extra stuff that create-react-app uses leaving you with barebones react.

Post the structure of your react-app here along with contents of index.html ...if u want to know what's wrong